# Set an option in the R tibble package

Tags: r, tibble

The tibble package at version 1.4.2 has options which are listed in the documentation under tibble-options. For example, one such option is tibble.max_extra_cols which defaults to 100.

How does one access and set these options?

Comment: Maybe `?options`?

Comment: And you can do this "permanently" via a startup script such as `~/.Rprofile`, or you system's `Rprofile.site` or a few others. See `help(Startup)`.  Many other useful options too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `options` to set and `getOption` to retrieve.  For example, below we set `"tibble.print_min"` to 3; then we show that we did indeed set it and display the 150 row iris dataset as a tibble noting that only 3 rows display.  Finally we set `"tibble.print_min"` back to its default noting that if `getOption("tibble.print_min")` returns NULL it means that the default will be used.  Now 10 rows are displayed.

```
library(tibble)

options(tibble.print_min = 3)
getOption("tibble.print_min")
## [1] 3

as.tibble(iris)
## # A tibble: 150 x 5
##   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
##          <dbl>       <dbl>        <dbl>       <dbl> <fct>  
## 1         5.10        3.50         1.40       0.200 setosa 
## 2         4.90        3.00         1.40       0.200 setosa 
## 3         4.70        3.20         1.30       0.200 setosa 
## # ... with 147 more rows

options(tibble.print_min = NULL)
getOption("tibble.print_min")
## [1] NULL

as.tibble(iris)
## # A tibble: 150 x 5
##    Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
##           <dbl>       <dbl>        <dbl>       <dbl> <fct>  
##  1         5.10        3.50         1.40       0.200 setosa 
##  2         4.90        3.00         1.40       0.200 setosa 
##  3         4.70        3.20         1.30       0.200 setosa 
##  4         4.60        3.10         1.50       0.200 setosa 
##  5         5.00        3.60         1.40       0.200 setosa 
##  6         5.40        3.90         1.70       0.400 setosa 
##  7         4.60        3.40         1.40       0.300 setosa 
##  8         5.00        3.40         1.50       0.200 setosa 
##  9         4.40        2.90         1.40       0.200 setosa 
## 10         4.90        3.10         1.50       0.100 setosa 
## # ... with 140 more rows
```